# How can I re-call API in case of axios intercepter error

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt

I am developing react project using JWT authentication and write this code.

```
const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 60000
});

service.interceptors.response.use( (response) => {
    return response.data
}, async (error) => {

        const originalRequest = error.config;
    
    // Remove token and redirect 
    if (error.response.status === 400 || error.response.status === 403) {
        localStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
        history.push(ENTRY_ROUTE)
        window.location.reload();
    }

    // Unauthorized error token should refresh with access token
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
        const jwtToken = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
        const token = JSON.parse(jwtToken)
        const refresh_token = token['refresh'];
        const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refresh_token.split('.')[1]));

        // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
        const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
        if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
            try {
                const res = await service.post('/authentication/token/refresh/', {refresh: refresh_token});
                localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, JSON.stringify(res));
                service.headers[TOKEN_PAYLOAD_KEY] = "JWT " + res['access'];
                originalRequest.headers[TOKEN_PAYLOAD_KEY] = "JWT " + res['access'];
                return service(originalRequest);
            }
            catch (error) {

            }
        }
        else {
            localStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
            history.push(ENTRY_ROUTE);
            window.location.reload();
        }

    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

This is working well and have no errors, but I have something to ask. When the token is expired and some API is called, I get 401 status code to get **access** token with refresh token. And it returns the **access** token correctly.

But there is no way to re-call the failed API ( just called with **expired access** token ). That's why there are cases I could have no response from the backend ( Imagine, user clicks button, but no response, so he should click the button again to see the response. This is because of calling with new **access** token again )

This code is used in all parts of the project and I have many API callings, so it seems impossible to re-call failed API in each react components.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `But there is no way to re-call the failed API`? You are calling the API again in your code. That doesn't work? Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: I think I call API again, but it doesn't work. As I mentioned, when the access token is experied and I try to get response from the server by hitting a button, I have to click twice, first is to get new access token, second is to get response from new token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of investigating my code, I finally found the answer.

Let me write my code and hope it will be helpful.

```
let refreshToken;

...
if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
            try {
                if (!refreshToken) {
                    refreshToken = service.post('/authentication/token/refresh/', {refresh: refresh_token}).then(token => {
                        refreshToken = null;
                        return token;
                    });
                }
                return refreshToken.then(res => {
                    localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, JSON.stringify(res));
                    service.defaults.headers[TOKEN_PAYLOAD_KEY] = "JWT " + res['access'];
                    originalRequest.headers[TOKEN_PAYLOAD_KEY] = "JWT " + res['access'];
                    return service(originalRequest);
                })
            }
            catch (error) {

            }
        }
        else {
            localStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
            history.push(ENTRY_ROUTE);
            window.location.reload();
        }
```

This prevents multiple token refresh API request and surely made the failed API call again with new *access* token.

Answer (score 3):

Best bet is to invoke axios again with the original request (with new token). I haven't tried setting up JWT server & executing this scenario, but something   like below should work:

```
const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 60000,
});

service.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response.data;
  },
  async (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

    // Remove token and redirect
    if (error.response.status === 400 || error.response.status === 403) {
      localStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
      history.push(ENTRY_ROUTE);
      window.location.reload();
    }

    if (error.response.status != 401) return Promise.reject(error);

    // Unauthorized error token should refresh with access token
    const jwtToken = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
    const token = JSON.parse(jwtToken);
    const refresh_token = token["refresh"];
    const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refresh_token.split(".")[1]));

    // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
    const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
    if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
      try {
        const res = await service.post("/authentication/token/refresh/", {
          refresh: refresh_token,
        });
        localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, JSON.stringify(res));
        service.headers[TOKEN_PAYLOAD_KEY] = "JWT " + res["access"];
        originalRequest.headers[TOKEN_PAYLOAD_KEY] = "JWT " + res["access"];

        axios
          .request(originalRequest)
          .then((response) => {
            Promise.resolve(response);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            Promise.reject(err);
          });
        //return service(originalRequest);
      } catch (error) {
        Promise.reject(error);
      }
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
      history.push(ENTRY_ROUTE);
      window.location.reload();
      Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's close, but still not fixed, could you improve more?

Comment: Remember that people on SO won't write your code for you. Ram's answer gives you some good guidance that you can now work with. If there's something wrong with the answer, you could maybe give some more detail. Why it's not working for you?